# Knapsack and set cover-like problem

Tags: np-complete, proof-techniques, knapsack-problems

Given $n$ sets $r_1, r_2, \cdots, r_n$ and a number $\delta$ where $0 \le \delta \le 1$. Let $T=\cup_{i=1}^{n}r_i=\{t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_m\}$. Each $t$ has a value $v(t)$, which is given to us.  The task is to find a subset $S$ of $T$ that minimize the total value $\sum_{t\in S}v(t)$ while guaranteeing $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{|r_i \cap S|}{|r_i|}>\delta n$.

Is this problem NP-complete? If so, which problem should I reduce from?

I've tried reduce it from the knapsack problem. One of the steps is not in P time and the attempt failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an instance of the following problem:

VECTOR-MINIMIZATION:
*Input:* vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^m$, a threshold $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$
*Goal:* minimize $v \cdot x$, subject to $w \cdot x \ge \gamma$ and $x \in \{0,1\}^m$

In your problem, $v=(v(t_1),\dots,v(t_m))$ and $w=(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ where $w_i = \sum_{t_i \in r_j} 1/|r_j|$, where the sum is over all $j$ such that the set $r_j$ contains the element $t_i$.

So, your problem is an instance of VECTOR-MINIMIZATION.  In turn, VECTOR-MINIMIZATION is basically an instance of the knapsack problem (it is at least as hard as knapsack, and thus NP-hard).

That raises the question, is your problem any easier than the general VECTOR-MINIMIZATION problem (or knapsack)?  In your problem, each $w_i$ has a special form: it is a sum of a polynomial number of reciprocals of polynomial-size integers.  I don't *think* there's any way to use the special structure of the $w_i$'s (and there are [exponentially many possible values](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2211989/14578) for the $w_i$'s), so I think your problem is NP-hard, but I don't have a proof at the moment.

That said, you can still use the standard algorithms for knapsack-like problems: e.g., integer linear programming (ILP).

Answer (score -1):

Try reducing from [Clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).  The $r_i$ are the vertex pairs in each edge (so $n$ will be the number of edges and $|r_i|=2$ for each $1 \le i \le n$).  Set $v_i=1$ for each $i$, and set $\delta = \frac{k(k-1)}{4n}-\epsilon$, where $k$ is the threshold parameter for the Clique problem instance and $\epsilon$ is some tiny positive amount to make the $> \delta n$ condition like $\ge \delta n$.  (If this produces $\delta > 1$, then add dummy vertices with huge costs and edges between them.)  This way we are trying to find the *fewest* vertices such that we get at least $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ edges, i.e., a $k$-clique.

Comment: It seems this does not work. As the vertexes selected are not guaranteed to be connected with each other. As each edge (set) contains two vertexes (elements), let's call a pair of a selected element and its set a 'half edge'. When reducing the solution, you guarantee there are $k(k-1)$ 'half edges'. However, these half edges are not guaranteed to be connected with each other (by connected, I mean the two half edges form a complete edge), which makes the solution of the original problem is not the solution to the clique problem. @j_random_hacker

Comment: You're right to say that these half edges are not constrained to form full edges with each other, but that doesn't matter: if there is a clique, then it is possible to choose a subset of just $k$ vertices that achieves $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ edges (and thus the required number of half-edges), meaning that there exists a solution $S$ having $\Sigma_{t\in S}{v(t)} = k$, while if there is no clique of size $k$, then you will need more than $k$ vertices to do so, so in that case every solution $S$ has $\Sigma_{t\in S}{v(t)} > k$.

Comment: The last sentence "if there is no clique of size k, then you will need more than k vertices to do so" seems skeptical. Think about a 'star' graph where only 1 vertex is connected with all the other vertexes and there is no extra edges. In this case, there is no k-clique while the vertex $t$ in the center itself can make $v(t)=\frac{m}{2}\gg \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ @j_random_hacker

Comment: Good point, I missed that a single vertex can add up to $m/2$ to the LHS required for the constraint.  (I guess you meant "while (setting $S$ to be) the vertex $t$ in the center itself can make $v(t)=1$ while $\Sigma_{i=1}^n{\frac{|r_i \cap S|}{|r_i|}} \gg \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$"?)  This makes me think of trying to reduce from Vertex Cover instead, but I can't see a way to get it to prefer to hit *every* edge over hitting *many* edges (possibly multiple times).  Maybe it's time to see if you can find a counterexample to a simple greedy algorithm, and if not, try to prove it correct?